# Не получается сделать универсальный SQL запрос для разных комбинаций заполненных полей в WinForms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server

Не получается сделать универсальный запрос. Хочу сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от заполненных полей производился поиск по БД, но при попытке поиска выдает просто всю таблицу...

```
"SELECT h.Name, h.Surname, h.Middle_name, h.Birthday, h.PhoneNumber, a.Name, h.House_number, h.Flat FROM dbo.Humen as h JOIN dbo.Addresses as a on h.Address_id=a.Id " +
"WHERE (h.Name = @humanName OR h.Name LIKE '%') " +
"AND (h.Surname = @surname OR h.Surname LIKE '%') " +
"AND (h.Middle_name = @middleName OR h.Middle_name LIKE '%') " +
"AND (h.Birthday = @birthday OR h.Birthday IN (SELECT Birthday FROM dbo.Humen)) " +
"AND (h.PhoneNumber = @phoneNumber OR h.PhoneNumber LIKE '%') " +
"AND (a.Name = @addressName OR a.Name LIKE '%') " +
"AND (h.House_number = @houseNumber OR h.House_number IN (SELECT House_number FROM dbo.Humen)) " +
"AND (h.Flat = @flat OR h.Flat IN (SELECT Flat FROM dbo.Humen));"
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: OR h.Name LIKE '%' Это Вас не смущает, это соответствие любой последовательности символов

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak ну да. Допустим, у меня попадает имя то, которое нужно, то что после OR , вроде как, не должно проверяться, а по другим полям выдаваться нужные комбинации.

Comment: подучите логику....основы основ

Comment: `h.Name = @humanName OR @humanName IS NULL` - похоже, вам нужно это. | Всегда рекомендую эту статью: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: Укажите используемый диалект SQL (используемую СУБД)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov MS SQL Server

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov по-моему так не выйдет. Т.е. если я не нахожу нужное имя, то он, как я понял, присвоит  полю humanName  значение null, и в итоге у меня будет запросе where name = null and surname = бла бла... В общем, не то. Мне нужно, чтобы, допустим, если я ввел только имя, мне вывело все данные людей, у которых это имя.

Comment: `присвоит полю humanName значение null` - нет. В запросе нет никаких присвоений полям.  Запрос читает данные отфильтровывая записи. `h.Name = @humanName OR @humanName IS NULL` следует понимать так: "вернуть запись если поле `Name` в таблице равно переданному параметру `humanName` или параметр `humanName` не задан вообще" это значит, что если `humanName` не задан, то условие `h.Name = @humanName` не берется во внимание вообще.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Спасибо. Уже целый день сижу, котелок на последнем издыхании, где присовение , где проверка уже сам не понимаю. Заметил, что если форму не заполнить, то на выходе будет пустая строка. Сейчас поправлю и попробую.

Comment: Покажите, как задаёте значение параметрам в C#. Если не заполнено, то нужно именно `null` задать, а не `string.Empty`, `""` и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `command.Parameters.Add("@humanName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = model.Name.Equals("") ? null : model.Name;` сейчас так. Однако у меня возникает исключение: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Параметризированный запрос "(@humanName nvarchar(4000),@surname nvarchar(4000),@middleName n" ожидает параметр "@humanName", который не был указан.` Само исключение возникает в строке, в котором создаю Reader `using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())`

Comment: Виноват. Используйте `DBNull.Value` вместо `null`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо огромное! Все работет!

Comment: Оформите ответ? И потом примите его. / И вам плюсик, и будущим поколениям польза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректный запрос

```
"SELECT h.Name, h.Surname, h.Middle_name, h.Birthday, h.PhoneNumber, a.Name, h.House_number, h.Flat FROM dbo.Humen as h JOIN dbo.Addresses as a on h.Address_id=a.Id " +
"WHERE (h.Name = @humanName OR @humanName IS NULL) " +
"AND (h.Surname = @surname OR @surname IS NULL) " +
"AND (h.Middle_name = @middleName OR @middleName IS NULL) " +
"AND (h.Birthday = @birthday OR @birthday IS NULL) " +
"AND (h.PhoneNumber = @phoneNumber OR @phoneNumber IS NULL) " +
"AND (a.Name = @addressName OR @addressName IS NULL) " +
"AND (h.House_number = @houseNumber OR @houseNumber IS NULL) " +
"AND (h.Flat = @flat OR @flat IS NULL);"
```

Так как если в WinForm не заполнить поле, на вход запрос поступит пустая строка. А из запроса следует, что необходимо не учитывать параметр, если он null, к примеру @addressName. Поэтому меняем пустые строки на DBNull.Value.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@addressName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
    model.AddressName.Equals("") ? DBNull.Value : model.AddressName;
```